# AJAX PUT call using odata returning server error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm trying to simply do a basic AJAX PUT call to my web API using ODATA.  It really shouldn't be that hard, and I've already got POST and GET to work, but PUT is being problematic.  Using Fiddler, it tells me: "The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. "  Here is what I have in my project (same thing I put in fiddler):

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "PUT",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "Outcome": callResult,
        "CallTimes": timeTried,

    }),
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Saved to database!");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        alert("Failed to save: " + xhr + "\n" + status + "\n" + err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you control the OData service implementation? If so, what does your controller method for PUT look like?

Comment: It's the default generated code from the .net api. Too long to post here...

Comment: What tool are you using to generate code?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 - I used the ASP.NET 4.5.2 Web API template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending the `Id` property as part of the `data` (payload). I'm guessing that causes the `Id` on the server-side to be deserialized as `null` or `0`, which most likely does not match the value of the entity key in your `url`. Hence, the code on the server thinks you are trying to modify the value of `Id`. (See "Updating an Entity" in [Create an OData v4 Endpoint Using ASP.NET Web API 2.2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint) for an example of a `Put` method that compares the entity key to the `Id` property in the request payload.)

Try adding the `Id` property to `data` as follows:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    "Id": key_value
    "Outcome": callResult,
    "CallTimes": timeTried,
})
```

where `key_value` is the value used as the entity key in your `url`.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Normally I think the odata URL query takes care of that with a id part of the url like http://localhost:11064/odata/ContactInfoes(4), but that error seems to have been replaced by another one. Thanks!